# List Custom URL in iTunes Episodes

Tags: itunes

I'm serving media from a website including RSS and iTunes. I want to log each request for a media title so I can track what media our partners are viewing and listening to. With RSS, I can create a custom PHP URL that logs the request before streaming the media.

But with iTunes, I don't get an episode list unless I include the enclosure tag which limits me to audio, video, or publication media types. Is there a way to include a custom URL for each item in iTunes XML?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Brandon